# JAAS / JAAC, DROOLS, or custom

Tags: java, security, hibernate, drools, jaas

I have been using my own internal custom authorization model which evaluates whether a user has permission to view, edit, delete, or create an item.  For instance, one place I use this is to determine if a user has permission to view a resource.  I have some restrictions such as whether the item is published, whether the user belongs to the necessary group / role, etc.

I store all of that information in a database where I audit the permissions and who changed them for a given entity.  To evaluate whether a user has permission, I have a Hibernate Event Listener that takes the current user and other contextual information and evaluates that against the entity.

Is this a good security model, would JAAS / JAAC or DROOLS work better here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of JAAS or a rule engine based solution, I'd consider [Apache Shiro](http://incubator.apache.org/shiro/) (formerly JSecurity) for *pluggable and flexible Authentication and Authorization*. Have a look at [What is Shiro?](http://incubator.apache.org/shiro/about.html).

But if you have a working solution, why not stick with it if it gets the job done.

Comment: It works, but it is my own home grown solution - if there is something that is more standardized, then I'd switch to that for maintenance reasons.  I'll look into Apache Shiro.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Security and Shiro are probably the most widely used security frameworks and I would probably use them for a project right now. However, it seems a shame to have a layer on top of an application server when and app server has fully tested and integrated security built in (JAAS). I am looking forward to seeing what [PicketBox](http://jboss.org/picketbox) has to offer, [Seam Security 3.0](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/SecurityModule) is built on it, it seems to more naturally fit with what an app server already offers, just with some nice features such as open id support.

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm a little late to the party, but [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/features.html) is a pretty robust option as well, specifically it's ACL module can do a lot of what you're looking for.